# Using a Dictionary to filter Pandas DataFrame, where the Keys correspond to the Column Names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, filter

I am trying to use the values of a dictionary to 'filter' a Pandas DataFrame, where the dictionary's keys correspond to the columns in the DataFrame.

Example:

```
In [5]: df                                                                                                                                                     
Out[5]: 
  Col1 Col2 Col3
0    A    L    Y
1    B    M    Y
2    B    N    Z                                                                                                   

In [7]: dict_example                                                                                                                                           
Out[7]: {'Col1': 'B', 'Col2': 'M', 'Col3': 'Y'}
```

The result I would want, based on the values in dict_example, would simply be the second row,

```
Out[5]: 
  Col1 Col2 Col3
1    B    M    Y
```

I have tried something like this:

```
In [8]: df[df.isin(dict_example.values())]                                                                                                                     
Out[8]: 
  Col1 Col2 Col3
0  NaN  NaN    Y
1    B    M    Y
2    B  NaN  NaN
```

But it is giving me back the whole DataFrame, instead of just the row, where all values from the dictionary correspond to the values in the DataFrame.

I could of course do something like this:

```
In [9]: df[(df['Col1']=='B')&(df['Col2']=='M')&(df['Col3']=='Y')]                                                                                              
Out[9]: 
  Col1 Col2 Col3
1    B    M    Y
```

But this gets increasingly difficult, the more dimensions you have to filter for.

I would be very grateful for any input!

Comment: `df[df.isin(dict_example.values())] .dropna()` ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
df[(df[list(dict_example)] == list(dict_example.values())).all(axis=1)]
```

Comment: Great, thank you! Works like a charm and exactly what I was looking for (a one liner that does the job)!

Answer (score 1):

You can try df.query method

```
df
>>
  Col1 Col2 Col3
0    A    L    X
1    B    M    Y
2    C    N    Z  

dict_query={'Col1': 'B', 'Col2': 'M', 'Col3': 'Y'}
search_query="&".join([str(x)+"=="+"'"+str(y)+"'" for x,y in dict_query.items()])
## This is the search query
search_query
>>
Col1=='B'&Col2=='M'&Col3=='Y'

df.query(search_query)
>>
Col1    Col2    Col3
1   B   M   Y
```

Just creating the appropriate query using string join, would do the trick